# What is the best combination of properties would be the most desirable for a cooking pot?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the best combination of properties would be the most desirable for a cooking pot? 
A)Low specific heat and high conductivity 
B)High specific heat and High conductivity

The answer in the book is A.
A cooking pot should absorb minimum heat and conduct maximum heat

But shouldn't it be High specific heat Because higher the specific heat of a substance more is heat absorbed and therefore more is the heat conducted?
Would be helpful if explained with equations

Comment: This is not only an engineering (rather than physics) question, but also *way* too broad since there are literally thousands of different types of pots, serving different purposes. Each type will have different requirements. *Perhaps* this could be on-topic on [cooking.se].

Answer (score 1):

A cooking pot should easily transfer heat to its content (high conductivity) and not requiring too much heat to get to the right temperature (low specific heat), because it would reduce efficiency, since you would spend more energy heating the pot instead of the content.

Ideally, you want your pot to transfer all the heat coming from the hob to its content (the pot would remain colder, not absorbing any heat, but of course, that's not possible).